# Android room - clearing sqlite_sequence is not working

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

Following code is not resetting/clearing the auto increment id to 0

```
database = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, DatabaseMeta.DB_NAME)
            .build();
database.query("DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name = ?", new Object[]{"tableName"});
```

or

```
database.query("REPLACE INTO sqlite_sequence (name, seq) VALUES ('mission', -1)", null);
```

Is there anyway to clear `sqlite_sequence` in Android room?

Android room is not using "sqlite_sequence" for auto increment logic i think, not sure. Tried printing `sqlite_sequence` entries, can't find the table name i used(which has the auto increment primary key).

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code works for me

```
class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    static final String DATABASE_NAME = DBConfig.DATABASE_NAME;

    FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
}

FeedReaderDbHelper mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(mainContext.getApplicationContext());
mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase().execSQL("DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name='table_name';");
```

Comment: Seems Android room wont support on clearing sqlite_sequence, which is explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53764393/3442067. Have to create our own SQLiteOpenHelper to clear or modify sqlite_sequence table.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm for determening the **rowid** when `AUTOINCREMENT` is used, and thus when **sqlite_sequence** is created/used, uses the higher of the highest existing **rowid** or the value (seq column) in the sqlite_sequence table.

As such if any rows exist in the associated table then setting  the seq column will have no effect if it is not a value greater than the highest **rowid** in the associated table.

If the table has no rows then I believe that dropping the table will result in the respective row in the sqlite_sequence table being removed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I put this function in my RoomDatabase class:

```
        companion object {

    fun resetPointer(nonRoomDb: MyRoomDatabase){

      nonRoomDb.openHelper.writableDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence")

}       
}
```

So you can call it everywhere in code:

```
    val database = MyRoomDatabase.getInstance(application)

    MyRoomDatabase.resetPointer(database)
```