# Reset auto-increment in Android's Room library

Tags: android, sqlite, auto-increment, android-room

I created a table using Android's Room library, which stores items of type `User`. For the ID column, the value is automatically generated by adding the annotation

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
```

In the next application run, I delete all entries in the table. However, the auto-generated value is not reset to 0, but continues where it left of the previous run.

How can I reset the auto-increment counter when I delete all entries in a table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Room - reset auto generated key on each app run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50878734/android-room-reset-auto-generated-key-on-each-app-run)

Comment: answered this recently: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53764393/549372

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58616764/9726986

Comment: if your main concern is running out of integers for the row id then you shouldn't worry about that. sqlite will start using unused integers if the largest ROWID is equal to the largest possible integer (9223372036854775807) https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: @lasec0203 thanks just what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Why would you, is perhaps the more pertinent question. A column with AUTOINCREMENT will be an alias of the **rowid** column which is used to uniquely identify a row. It isn't the best practice to rely upon this value other than for identifying a row.

Using AUTOINCREMENT (autogenerate = true) results in an internal table **sqlite_sequence** being created, a row in that table holds the value of the highest ever used **rowid** The next **rowid** will be that values + 1. Hence your issue.

As such to restart from 1 you would have to either update the respective row in the **sqlite_sequence** table to 0 or delete the respective row in the **sqlite_sequence** table.

You may wish to have a look at [Android Room - reset auto generated key on each app run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50878734/android-room-reset-auto-generated-key-on-each-app-run?noredirect=1&lq=1). **Noting** that this could be the basis for resetting the sequence value, **but** that it will always resets the sequence value.

Comment: are you sure this still works with the current version of `Room`? recently I've spent a whole night with this, until I found out that `SupportSQLiteDatabase` rejects all `UPDATE` and `DELETE` queries on internal tables.

Comment: That would depend upon what **this** is referring to. If it's the underlying principle of altering the respective row in **sqlite_sequence** then I don't believe that room uses anything other than the sqlite supplied with Android and due to historical versions would have to support this and not use some specially compiled version of SQLite that forces all tables to be WITHOUT rowid tables.

Comment: also thought so... but it uses `SupportSQLiteDatabase`, which delegates to an implementation of `SQLiteDatabase`, instead of using the bare `SQLiteDatabase`... and that's the problem. only `SQLiteDatabase` will run queries which manipulate the internal tables. the answer linked in the comments above has an example project linked.

Comment: No the issue is that sqlite_sequence stores the highest ever used rowid when AUTOINCREMENT (AUTOGENERATE = True) is used. Got nothing to do with SQliteDatabase v SupportSQliteDatabase.

Comment: @MartinZeitler If by **this** (are you sure this still works with the current version of Room?) you are talking about the linked answer (which I believe is not the exact same issue, but is similar)? Then if you were to look at the code you will see that it uses **SQLiteDatabase** and does so BEFORE room opens the database, and as such opens the database using the **SQLiteDatabase open** method, and thus uses the **SQLiteDatabase execSQL** method. So I do believe that it still works.