# Android Room Database allways start with Primarykey 0 for new Entrys

Tags: android, kotlin, primary-key, android-room

I get an array with a not specified number of BlueCones with different x and y Values, every 0.5s I receive new BlueCones that should Replace the old Cones in the "blue_cone" table how can I auto-generate Keys that always start with 0 for new Incoming Cones.

```
@Entity(tableName ="blue_cones")
data class BlueCone(

val x: Double = 0.0,
val y: Double = 0.0

){
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var blueId: Int = 0

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Room` does not support resetting the primary keys, which are `UNIQUE`. one option would be adding two further fields, which form a combined key:  eg. `sequence` (the number of the request) & `coneId`, where `coneId` could start over at 0, with every new request/response. I've also once explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53764393/549372) how to reset an auto-incremental value, in case it has to be (but ordinary this is not recommend).

as @Advice-Dog suggested yesterday, blue & yellow should be properties of class `Cone`. can only confirm, that this would make sense, with high probability... unless there is a strict requirement, to store them in two separate tables.